# Is there a way to check if any items in a string array are in a string in Snowflake/Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a way to check if a string contains any words in another field which is a single string that holds a list of items. Something like this...

```
id              items (STRING)
1            burger;hotdog
```

I have a second dataset that might look like...

```
transaction_id       description           amount
     10              cheeseburger            10
```

Now I need to grab the amount if the description matches any items in the first table, in this case it does match with the string burger, however, i can't seem to get the SQL right since if I were to use **LIKE ANY** in Snowflake, i'd need to pass in **('%burger%",'%hotdog%') which are two separate strings - in this case I can't make explicit calls as each id/item permutation may be different in the first table. While in Redshift when I try to use

```
CASE WHEN lower(t.description) SIMILAR TO '%(' || replace(items,';','|') || ')%' then amount END
```

I get the following error: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting a snowflake answer:

```
WITH keys AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'burger;hotdog') a(id,items)
), data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (10,'cheeseburger',10) b(transaction_id, description, amount)
), seq_keys AS (
    SELECT s.seq_id, f.value as key
    FROM (
        SELECT seq8() as seq_id, k.*
        FROM keys AS k
    ) AS s
    ,lateral flatten(input=>split(s.items,';')) F
)
SELECT d.*, sk.*
FORM data d 
JOIN seq_keys sk ON d.description ILIKE '%'||sk.key||'%'
```

gives:

```
TRANSACTION_ID  DESCRIPTION AMOUNT  SEQ_ID  KEY
10  cheeseburger    10  0   "burger"
```

which is you distinct on the SEQ_ID then you can de-dupe if there are multi keys that match.. I would be inclined to also add an ID to the "data table".

Comment: thank you! this was perfect. What's the point of using seq8(), just for deduping the ids?

Comment: yes, just to de-dupe, to allow finding the number of matched "keys" prior to breaking them up. Aka wasn't sure how you needed want to do with the results after this step.